# sql проблема с секундами в getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @time DATE = getdate()
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
  DECLARE @sec AS INT = DATEDIFF( second, @time, getdate());
  PRINT cast( @sec as varchar(6));
END;  
GO
```

почему высветливается 73596 вместо 2 секунд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить формат с DATE на DATETIME

```
DECLARE @time DATETIME= getdate()
```